# OAuth 1.0 POST - "Invalid Signature" C#

Tags: c#, .net, oauth

I'm making calls to the following [StackPath](https://api.stackpath.com)

I've tried various existing libraries, such as [oauth](https://github.com/danielcrenna/vault/tree/master/oauth) and [MaxCDN](https://github.com/MaxCDN/dotnet-maxcdn) all of which return the response:

```
{"code":500,"error":{"message":"Invalid signature","type":""}}
```

All Get requests using the above oauth library work fine, but not for POST.

Using Postman I was able to make a successful post to the API, but I'm not sure how they generate their signatures using the Authorization tab.

I created a class to create the Authorization manually using the following...

sb creates the value of the Authorization header:

```
public string GenerateAuthorizationHeader(string method, string url)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("OAuth ");
    sb.Append("oauth_consumer_key=\"" + _consumer_key + "\",");
    sb.Append("oauth_nonce=\"" + _nonce + "\",");
    sb.Append("oauth_signature=\"" + GetSignature() + "\",");
    sb.Append("oauth_signature_method=\"" + _signature_method + "\",");
    sb.Append("oauth_timestamp=\"" + _timestamp + "\",");
    sb.Append("oauth_version=\"" + _version + "\"");

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

GetSignature() creates a base string:

```
private string GetSignatureBaseString()
{
    string basestring = "oauth_consumer_key=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(_consumer_key);
    basestring += "&" + "oauth_nonce=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(_nonce);
    basestring += "&" + "oauth_signature_method=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(_signature_method);
    basestring += "&" + "oauth_timestamp=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(_timestamp);
    basestring += "&" + "oauth_version=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(_version);

    basestring = _method + "&" + Uri.EscapeDataString(_url) + "&" + Uri.EscapeDataString(basestring);

    return basestring;
}
```

Base string is hashed using the consumer secret and GetSignature() returns the string:

```
private string GetHashedSignature(string baseString)
{
    var encode = new ASCIIEncoding();

    byte[] keyBytes = encode.GetBytes(_consumer_secret);
    byte[] msgBytes = encode.GetBytes(baseString);

    string result = "";

    using (HMACSHA1 sha1 = new HMACSHA1(keyBytes))
    {
        var hashed = sha1.ComputeHash(msgBytes);
        result = Convert.ToBase64String(hashed);
    }

    return Uri.EscapeDataString(result);
}
```

Both GET and POST fail using my code. Can anyone find fault in my code, or provide any information on how Postman generate their OAuth 1.0 Authorization header values, specifically oauth_signature?

**Edit I went with RestSharp - feel free to answer for future users.

Answer (score 0):

You are forming the base string incorrectly. Specifically, [RFC 5849 §3.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4.1) gives precise guidelines for how the URI path and query parameters (or entity request body) must be normalized, ordered, and escaped. `Uri.EscapeDataString(_url)` is not sufficient.

I would recommend using an existing, well-tested library to create the signature, rather than reimplementing the RFC from scratch.